# Which functions/classes are available during SHORTINIT?

Tags: functions, init

When we want to load WP core with:

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require( __DIR__ .'/wp-load.php');
```

Which WordPress functions are available for us? i.e. `get_option, WP_Query` ... or which ones are available then? Is there any documentation?

Answer (score -2):

I've found they can be listed by `get_declared_classes()`, `get_defined_functions()`, which return all list of available functions.

(full list is [here](https://puvox.software/blog/available-functions-class-during-shortinit-wp/) )

Comment: funny, why downvotes?